# Properly justify text on specific scenario

Tags: jquery, html, css, mysql

I'm struggling with a detail on a project and I can't see any solution. We're getting datas writen by an Ai from a MySQL bdd and showing them as text in a fancy way http://82.223.18.239/writing.php

As you can see, the text isn't properly justified in the begining and I don't know how to fix this. Any help ?

Our wip code

```
<head>
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css"> 
        #myTable{ 
           width:"90%";
           min-width:250px;
           white-space: pre-wrap;
           word-wrap:break-word;
           position:absolute;
           border:solid 0px;
           top:200px;
           left:720px;
           right:720px;
           bottom:50px;
           font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
           text-align:justify
        } 

        #body       {
            padding-bottom:60px;
            overflow:auto;
            height:800px;
                   }

   </style> 

</head>

<body>
    <div id="myTable"> <div>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        var skip = 0;
        function get_data(index) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'getData.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data: ({"skip":skip}),
                success : function(data) { 
                    if(data && data.trim()!='') {
                        skip = skip+1;
                        showText("#myTable", data, 0, 2); 
                    }
                    else {
                        setTimeout(function () { get_data(skip); }, 30000);
                    }
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Request error : "+JSON.stringify(request));
                }
            });
        }

        function showText(target, message, index, interval) {   
            if (index < message.length) {
                $(target).append(message[index++]);
                setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
            }
            else {
                get_data(skip);
            }
        }

        //var period = 10000; //NOTE: period is passed in milliseconds
        get_data(skip);
        //setInterval(page_refresh, period); 
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: HI Mathieu. It appears the 'white-space' attribute is playing a part here. When the information from the DB is produced, how are you defining the paragraph breaks?

Comment: The text is outputted through torch-rnn in a (UTF-8 ?) file then pushed into the bdd as json datas. The A.I writes almost by itself so it's not html tags but others line breaks I suppose...

Comment: Of course the justification behavior changes dynamically, if you are dynamically changing the text length as well. I guess if you want to get rid of this effect, then your only choice is to have the whole text laid out from the beginning, and “hide” the remaining characters only visually (text-color like background color or transparent, or maybe visibility:hidden if you want to prevent that a user that select all content on the page could see it before it is fully “revealed”.)

Answer (score 0):

Updated CSS:

```
#myTable {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: absolute;    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-align: justify;
}
#body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: The text is occupying all the screen

Comment: So you don't want to occupy all the screen from left to right??

Comment: No, just justify the text properly in the middle of the screen. I'm sorry if my english made my question... not clear :/

Now, it's justified but not immediately. The text is shown, and then, when it hit the limit of its box, it's justified.